# Android emulation cant show imageView imageButton

Tags: android, imageview

Heloo prease helo me !!! I send on this problem dwo days, please !!
http://pastebin.com/fpAfJxV0
that was my activity code
imageView do not show during emulation in android studio 2.2
My activityView and emulation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFpyg.png)

Comment: Instead of taking screenshots it is better to provide code here to make question helpful for everyone after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't panic, relax and just use android:src. 
For your knowledge, srcCompat is used only for vector drawables since android support library 23.2.0. And to enable it, you have to include

```
 android {  
     defaultConfig {  
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
     }  
 }
```

in build.gradle